# Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'String?'

Tags: swift

I am very new to swift. Whenever i try to run my code I get this error.

> Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'String?'

How do I go about fixing it? Thanks in advance

```
func getWaterVolumeLabelText() -> Double {
   let dnv: Double = dNTPsVolumeLabel.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0
        let fp: Double = forwardPrimerLabel.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0
        let rp: Double = reversePrimerLabel.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0
        let dp: Double = dnaPolymeraseLabel.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0
      //  let votd: Double = volumeOfTemplateDna.text.doubleValue() ?? 0
        let bv: Double = bufferVolumeLabel.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0


        waterVolumeLabel.text = (numberOfSamples.doubleValue() ) * (50.0 - dnv )// This is where the error shows.
        }
```

Comment: let votd: Double = volumeOfTemplateDna.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0

Comment: that line throws an error so i have it commented out for now

Comment: You just need to initialize a new String with the result of your expression. `let result = numberOfSamples.doubleValue() * (50.0 - dnv)` and `waterVolumeLabel.text = String(result)`

Comment: btw text is optional but its default value is an empty String. So you can safely force unwrap the result. `dNTPsVolumeLabel.text!.doubleValue()`

Comment: Seems kind of obvious. How can a `text` be a `doubleValue`? The text is a String, the number is a Double, you can't assign the one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `Double` value to `String` type that's why it gives error. You can convert `Double` to `String`. Your updated code:

```
func getWaterVolumeLabelText() -> Double {
   let dnv: Double = dNTPsVolumeLabel.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0
        let fp: Double = forwardPrimerLabel.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0
        let rp: Double = reversePrimerLabel.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0
        let dp: Double = dnaPolymeraseLabel.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0
      //  let votd: Double = volumeOfTemplateDna.text.doubleValue() ?? 0
        let bv: Double = bufferVolumeLabel.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0

        let finalResult = (numberOfSamples.doubleValue() ) * (50.0 - dnv )
        waterVolumeLabel.text = String(finalResult)
        }
```

Comment: I added this code and uncommented `let votd: Double = volumeOfTemplateDna.text?.doubleValue() ?? 0`  Now my error says _Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Any'_